# Django - the effect on page load speed of using include tag inside for loop

Tags: django

The odds are that this question will be banned, because this forum seems to me a site for "why it doesn't work"-type of questions, rather than "is it a good idea to do what I do" ones. And yet, I am very much concerned about preserving DRY-ness in my code.

I have a Django template which looks like this:

```
<ol id = 'task_list'>
    {% for item in qs %}
        {% include 'list_item.html' with item=item %}
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

list_item.html:

```
<li>
   {{item}}
</li>
```

- **The advantage** (at least, for me) of this code: it positively affects DRYness when I have a ajax code which posts a request for creating new items of the list and renders them on the client side subsequently:

JS:

```
$.post('my_view_url', function(response)
    $('#container').append(response);
```

Django view:

```
def my_view(response)
   #... 
   return render_to_response('list_item.html',....)
```

This way, `list_item.html` helps me use the same HTML code for both initial rendering of existing elements and client-side rendering of newly created items.

- **The disadvantage** is that `{% include %}` is known to be rather slow.

**The question**: Is this code pattern not a performance killer in case of paginated rendering of large arrays of data ?

*Additional note:*

*AFAIK, {% block %} is faster than {% include %}. But I've got no idea how to rewrite the code pattern using `block`.*

Comment: Nothing wrong with this post: you've asked a well defined question, which has a specific answer.

Comment: If you are concerned about performance, you could try opbeat to check how long it takes to render. Also, you can cache the block if it does not change that often, even if it is not that long.

Comment: So performance is pretty brutal with this. Take our example, a listing of products in a grid. We use this time and time throughout the page, using include / load inside those templates has very poor performance as the needed template tags & filters are loaded everytime with include. Wondering if there is another way to go about it...